# subtraction game input value 1 to 7?

Tags: c++

i have a trouble, i make a subtraction game program use C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int total = 1, n = 0;
    cout << "Welcome to NIM. Pick a starting total: ";
    cin >> total;
    while (total == 0) {
        cout << "wrong number" << endl;
        cin >> total;
        total--;
    }

    while (true) {
        // Pick best response and print results.
        if ((total % 3) == 2) {
            total = total - 2;
            cout << "I am subtracting " << endl;
        }
        else {
            total--;
            cout << "I am subtracting " << endl;
        }
        cout << "New total is " << total << endl;
        if (total == 0) {
            cout << "I win!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        // Get user's response; must be 1 or 2.
        cout << "Enter num to subtract (1 to 7): ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n == 1 && n == 7) {
            cout << "Input must be 1 to 7 ." << endl;
            cout << "Re-enter: ";
            cin >> n;
        }

        total = total - n;
        cout << "New total is " << total << endl;
        while (total < 0) {
            cout << "total should 0" << endl;
            cin >> total;
            break;
        }

        if (total == 0) {
            cout << "You win!" << endl;

            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i can input value 1 to 7 but the comp input only value 1 and 2, i want comp can input 1 to 7 too.
i tried an other way i use even and odd numbers for subtraction variable "total" for example if the total value is an even number subtract even numbers 2,4,6 if the total value is an odd number subtract odd numbers 1,3,7 but it output the comp only subtract value 1.

```
while (true) {
         // Pick best response and print results.
            if ( n1 == 1 && n1 == 7){

                if  (n1 % 2 == 0){

                }

              total = total - n1;
```

output expected example i start the number 10,
i subtraction 4 from the total, making it 6.
comp also subtract 5 from the total, making 1.
i subtraction 1 from the total, making it 0 and i win.
so subtration to get zero and will win. so i want comp can input subtraction value 1 to 7.

what should i do?

Comment: what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ? Please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: `if (n == 1 && n == 7)` can never be true.

Comment: @aynos no error messages

Comment: Okay then what are the outputs what are the expected outputs and what do you put in?

Comment: @Aynos output expected example i start the number 10, i subtraction 4 from the total, making it 6. comp also subtract 5 from the total, making 1. i subtraction 1 from the total, making it 0 and i win. so subtration to get zero and will win. so i want comp can input subtraction value 1 to 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Get user's response; must be 1 or 2.
    cout << "Enter num to subtract (1 to 7): ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1 && n == 7) {
        cout << "Input must be 1 to 7 ." << endl;
        cout << "Re-enter: ";
        cin >> n;
    }
```

This `if (n == 1 && n == 7)` statement can never be true. As far as i understand from your output line, you want to check the condition of the entered number not being between 1 & 7.

Hence, changing your if statement to `if (n < 1 || n > 7)` might solve your problem, since it will only be true if the entered number is less than 1 or greater than 7.

Comment: output what i mean  i start the number 10, i subtraction 4 from the total, making it 6. comp also subtract 5 from the total, making 1. i subtraction 1 from the total, making it 0 and i win. i change if (n < 1 || n > 7) but when i start number 10 program end. subtraction game I vs comp so for example i can subtrac number 1 to 7 but comp subtract only number 1 and 2 if i can input number 1 to 7 i easy win.